# Is there a way to rewrite ?search= to /news/ in .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Probably not.. but..

I there a way to rewrite `?search=` and make it read `/news/` in `.htaccess`?

So `mydomain.com/?search=frogs` would be:  `mydomain.com/news/frogs`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to set a rewrite rule in .htaccess that does an HTTP redirect to cause the browser to request the new URL. I would recommend a 301 (permanent redirect) response code unless this is temporary, in which case use 302.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^$ /news/%1? [L,R=301]
```

Should work, although I haven't tested. Here's a [good rundown](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-rewriterule-and-query-string/) of some of the issues redirecting a URL with a querystring to a URL without one.

**EDIT:** after testing, changed the first argument of the RewriteRule from `^/$` to `^$`. Should work now for URLs like `example.com/?search=foo`.

Answer (score 0):

simples...

```
RewriteRule ^/news/(.*)$ index.php?search=$1 [NC,L]
```